# Enviar valores de input checkbox, somente os selecionados para window.open()

Tags: javascript, html, input

Gostaria de enviar os valores do checkbox, somente os selecionados para uma página usando o `window.open()`:

```
<div class='checkbox'>
    <label><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value='Teste1'> Teste1</label>
<div>
<div class='checkbox'>
    <label><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value='Teste2'> Teste2</label>
<div>
<div class='checkbox'>
    <label><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value='Teste3'> Teste3</label>
<div>
<div class='checkbox'>
    <label><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value='Teste4'> Teste4</label>
<div>
<div class='checkbox'>
    <label><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value='Teste5'> Teste5</label>
<div>
<div class='btn-box'>
    <button class='btn btn-info'>Enviar</button>
</div>
```

Tentei desse modo mas os valores são enviados assim:

```
<script>
    $('.checkbox .btn').click(function(){
         var inputValores = $('.checkbox input').serialize();
         window.open('destino.php?' + inputValores);
    });
</script>
```

A URL FICA:

```
destino.php?checkbox=Teste1&checkbox=Teste2&checkbox=Teste3....
```

PODE SER ENVIADO ASSIM?

```
destino.php?checkbox[].....
```

Comment: Está usando jQuery?

Comment: Oi Fernandosavio resolvi o b.o., postei a solução abaixo, obrigado pela atenção!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode enviar via POST. Basta colocar os checkboxes dentro de um `form`. Depois abrir uma nova aba com `window.open()` dando um nome à aba, e fazer um submit apontando para o nome da aba:

```
<form name="boxes" method="post" action="destino.php" target="destino">
   <div class='checkbox'>
       <label><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value='Teste1'> Teste1</label>
   </div>
   <div class='checkbox'>
       <label><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value='Teste2'> Teste2</label>
   </div>
   <div class='checkbox'>
       <label><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value='Teste3'> Teste3</label>
   </div>
   <div class='checkbox'>
       <label><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value='Teste4'> Teste4</label>
   </div>
   <div class='checkbox'>
       <label><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value='Teste5'> Teste5</label>
   </div>
   <div class='btn-box'>
       <button class='btn btn-info'>Enviar</button>
   </div>
</form>

<script>
$('.btn-box button.btn').click(function(){
   window.open(null, 'destino');
   document.forms.boxes.submit();
});
</script>
```

Nesta linha:

```
window.open(null, 'destino');
```

O 1º argumento `null` seria a página a ser aberta, mas ela será carregada pelo atributo `action` do `form`. E o 2º argumento `'destino'` é o nome da aba, onde o atributo `target` tem o mesmo valor e para onde irá enviar o formulário.

Comment: Não pode enviar via POST, foge do propósito. Já resolvi e obrigado pela atenção prestada.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi o B.O. do seguinte modo:

```
<div class='checkbox'>
    <label><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value='Teste1'> Teste1</label>
<div>
<div class='checkbox'>
    <label><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value='Teste2'> Teste2</label>
<div>
<div class='checkbox'>
    <label><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value='Teste3'> Teste3</label>
<div>
<div class='checkbox'>
    <label><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value='Teste4'> Teste4</label>
<div>
<div class='checkbox'>
    <label><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value='Teste5'> Teste5</label>
<div>
<div class='btn-box'>
    <button class='btn btn-info'>Enviar</button>
</div>

<script>
    $('.btn-box button.btn').click(function(){
        var valores= new Array();
        $(".checkbox input:checked").each(function () {
           valores.push( $(this).val() );
        });
        parent.location.href='destino.php?arr=' + valores + '';
    });
</script>
```